# C fopen won't open file when run in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, fopen

I have problem with using fopen to open file for read in eclipse. The file I'm trying to open is in the same directory as all program files, it has all permissions granted. But the file can't be found by the program.

in program trying to open file with only the file name (without path):

```
if (!(file=fopen(name,"r"))){   
    fprintf(stderr,"Can't open file: '%s\n", name);
            exit(0);
}
```

I get "Can't open file:filename" for existent file in same directory with all permissions.

When I run it from shell it returns segmentation fault for existing file .I guess it succeeds in opening it , cause for non-existing file it returns that file not found. I figure it encounters error further in the program.

The question is could it be that eclipse searches in other directory than one with the executable file? How can I find it out? How can I fix it?

Comment: You really didn't provide us any concrete information to help you.

Comment: what information else is needed?

Comment: Some code, for example. If your program crashes, you wrote it wrong, which is something we can't fix without seeing the code.

Comment: Umm... From the top of my head: are you opening the file using an absolute or relative path? Is the working directory always the same?

Comment: There could even be an `if (fp = NULL) {}` on line 42 ... Hint: try adding an getcwd() function call.

Comment: it's relative path. I added info in the question

Answer (score 2):

There is a `Working Directory` setting in the Run Configurations dialog, under the Arguments tab in CDT. The value of the Working Directory is stored in the launch configuration (xml file). The default location is your current workspace. You can copy the file to this location or change the location to the directory with your input file. You can also use absolute path to make sure.

Comment: It fixed it.I changed the working directory where you pointed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The file you're trying to open is in the same directory as all the program files, but that's not the directory where the program is executed.

You need to check where your program is being created, and put the file in that same directory.